# Scraping issue with embedded span. Don't print the nested child

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a code (part of it) where I use beautifulsoup to scrape the text from `H3`:

```
company_name = job.find('h3', class_= 'joblist-comp-name').text.strip()
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<h3 class="joblist-comp-name">
    ARK INFOSOFT
     <span class="comp-more">(<a href="/candidate/companySearchResult.html?from=submit&amp;encid=D07qkDVGY__PLUS__9zpSvf__PLUS__uAgZw==&amp;searchType=byCompany&amp;luceneResultSize=25" class="jobs-frm-comp">More Jobs</a>) </span> 
    </h3>
```

My Result Looks like this:

```
Comapny Name: ARK INFOSOFT
     (More Jobs)
```

As I understand, this code grabs the text inside the `a` tag which is inside the `span` which is inside the `h3`. I only wanted the text "ARK INFOSOFT. How can I avoid grabbing any other text within `span`'s or `a` tags in the `h3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to not get the nested `span`:

1. Find the class you want.
2. Call the [`find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method on the found class, which will only return the **first** found match, and exclude the nested `span`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<h3 class="joblist-comp-name">
    ARK INFOSOFT
     <span class="comp-more">(<a href="/candidate/companySearchResult.html?from=submit&amp;encid=D07qkDVGY__PLUS__9zpSvf__PLUS__uAgZw==&amp;searchType=byCompany&amp;luceneResultSize=25" class="jobs-frm-comp">More Jobs</a>) </span> 
    </h3>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
company_name = soup.find("h3", class_="joblist-comp-name").find_next(text=True).strip()
```

---

Another option: use [`.contents`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children):

```
company_name = soup.find("h3", class_="joblist-comp-name").contents[0].strip()
```

Output (in both examples):

```
>>> print(company_name)
ARK INFOSOFT
```